# Count the number of times each of the symbols appears in a string - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, count, symbols

In this question, you are given a string s which represents a DNA string. The string s consists of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'. An example of a length 21 DNA string is "ATGCTTCAGAAAGGTCTTACG."

Your task is to write a code which will count the number of times each of the symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T' occur in s. Your code should generate a list of 4 integers and print it out.

```
# Here is the DNA string:
    s = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
    # Type your code here
```

Incorrectly, I wrote the string with spaces between letters.

```
s='A G C T T T T C A T T C T G A C T G C A A C G G G C A A T A T G T C T C T G T G T G G A T T A A A A A A A G A G T G T C T G A T A G C A G C'
list_of_symbols=s.split(sep=' ')
list_of_symbols
word_count_dictionary={}
for A in list_of_symbols:
    if A not in word_count_dictionary:
        word_count_dictionary[A]=1
    else:
        word_count_dictionary[A]+=1
```

Comment: Append your string to a list and use the Counter method:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do what [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) does:

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'

print(Counter(s))
```

From there to get list of counts, use:

```
Counter(s).values()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically on the right track but there's no need to split the string since Python already offers you the ability to loop through each character of the string.

A modified version of your attempt would be:

```
s = 'AGCTTTTCATTCTGACTGCAACGGGCAATATGTCTCTGTGTGGATTAAAAAAAGAGTGTCTGATAGCAGC'
word_count_dictionary = {}

for c in s:
    if c not in word_count_dictionary:
        word_count_dictionary[c] = 1
    else:
        word_count_dictionary[c] += 1

print(word_count_dictionary)
```